# How to set FirebaseClient Url?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new with **firebase**, I am trying to set `firebaseClient` URL for my project that exists in the attached picture, what I should put instead of xxxxx
 I am using cloud **firestore**

```
FirebaseClient firebase = new FirebaseClient("https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com/");
```

[image]

Comment: You may be using the wrong SDK. Check the following firestore examples. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/blob/f7b7e53bb48721f30cdb6b4066271e93b22f5403/firestore/api/Quickstart/Program.cs#L37-L38

Comment: Read the document here may help: [firestore/quickstart](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart).